# Show the translated result before microsoft(Bing)-translator-api finish its own task on android

Tags: android

I am trying to use the microsoft--translator-api.

I want to translate "hello" to Spanish.

I have tried the code below, but the result is "After translated:none", not "After translated:hola".

Any solution? thx

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Translate.setClientId("My ID");//CHANGE THIS
       Translate.setClientSecret("My key"); //CHANGE THIS
       String translatedText = "none";

       try {
        translatedText = Translate.execute("hello",Language.ENGLISH,Language.SPANISH );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       textView.setText("After translated:"+translatedText);
}
```

here is the logcat:

> 11-15 23:25:48.488: W/System.err(15449): java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : null
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:202)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:61)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at com.example.threadtranslate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
>   11-15 23:25:48.500: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
>   11-15 23:25:48.503: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
>   11-15 23:25:48.503: W/System.err(15449):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   11-15 23:25:48.503: W/System.err(15449):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   11-15 23:25:48.503: W/System.err(15449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
>   11-15 23:25:48.503: W/System.err(15449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-15 23:25:48.503: W/System.err(15449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   11-15 23:25:48.507: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>   11-15 23:25:48.507: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
>   11-15 23:25:48.515: W/System.err(15449):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-15 23:25:48.515: W/System.err(15449): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>   11-15 23:25:48.519: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>   11-15 23:25:48.523: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>   11-15 23:25:48.523: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>   11-15 23:25:48.527: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>   11-15 23:25:48.531: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>   11-15 23:25:48.531: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>   11-15 23:25:48.535: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
>   11-15 23:25:48.539: W/System.err(15449):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>   11-15 23:25:48.539: W/System.err(15449):    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.getToken(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:133)
>   11-15 23:25:48.539: W/System.err(15449):    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveResponse(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:160)
>   11-15 23:25:48.539: W/System.err(15449):    at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:199)
>   11-15 23:25:48.539: W/System.err(15449):    ... 16 more

Comment: Any errors in LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your keys and make sure you have the internet permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I had enabled INTERNET permission.and the keys works fine in my other project.